Can we have a [elision] tag?
Elision is a common feature of the Italian language and I have just noticed there is no tag for it in Italian Stack Exchange. Could we add it ?
Some questions which could use the new tag:

When do we elide “dove è” into “dov'è”?
Why "quest'anno" but "questo autunno"?
"l'FBI" vs "lo FBI"
Obligatory elisions


Yes, in my opinion it may be useful to create a tag elision or apostrophe. In fact, you can do it yourself without any problem because you only need 150 points of reputation on this site in order to be able to do it.
